# Anchor to element redirects to home page on IIS based dynamic page

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, ckeditor, anchor

I use CKEditor to create content for blog articles that are stored in a database and served on a ASP.NET site, using *rewrite* module to parse slugs and show the corresponding page.
In one of the page (*myblog.com/articles/1/article1*) I want to add an anchor that scrolls up to the top of the page, so I do:

```
<h1 name="toppage">Article Title</h1>

... lots of content here

<a href="#toppage">Go to top</a>
```

The problem is that on the front-end, the link of that anchor is *myblog.com/#toppage* and when I click on it, it brings me to the home page. It should be *myblog.com/articles/1/article1#toppage* but either the server or CKEditor cannot make sure the anchor keeps the user on the same page and just goes to the anchored element.

Is this about the server? Should CKEditor generate the full URL? How does it do that, because on the back-end we don't know yet the generated URL's slug